# Is the hash function $h(x\|y) = AES_x( y)$ collision resistant?

Tags: hash, aes, cryptanalysis, collision-resistance

If $x$ and $y$ are both 128-bit strings would the function $h(x||y) = AES_x(y)$, where $x\|y$ means concatenation, be considered collision resistant ?

- Is there an easy way to find $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ such that $h(x_1\|y_1) = h(x_2\|y_2)$ ?

I couldn't think of a way but since the hash function is un-keyed something tells me that there is a way to manipulate the key/string pairs?

Comment: is this a homework? Hint: what happens if you can find a collision?

Comment: @kelalaka, I suppose that if the keys are different as well as the texts then collisions are possible in theory, since we have 2^256 options for the input and only 2^128 options for the output. But that doesn't contradict anything about AES, does it ?

Comment: What i thought is that in average we will have to try 2^128 options to find a collision when they keys are different because in average every 2^128 strings from the 2^256 will map to a single ciphertext (and there are 2^128 ciphertexts)

What i'm looking for is a formal proof of what you've mentioned - because brute-force is always correct but how can we prove that no other way exists to break it ?

Comment: @kelalaka Er, no, AES decryption does not require brute force. Given a ciphertext $c$ and an arbitrary key $k$, you can find a plaintext $p$ such that $E_k(p) = c$. What would be difficult would be to find $k$ given $p$ and $c$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't even second-preimage resistant. Hint:

> $y = \mathrm{AES}^{-1}_{x}(\mathrm{AES}_{x}(y))$

For any 128-bit string $x_1$, $x_2$ and $y_1$,

> $h(x_1||y_1) = \mathrm{AES}_{x_1}(y_1) = \mathrm{AES}_{x_2}\left(\mathrm{AES}^{-1}_{x_2}(\mathrm{AES}_{x_1}(y_1))\right) = h\left(x_2 || \mathrm{AES}^{-1}_{x_2}(\mathrm{AES}_{x_1}(y_1))\right)$

Follow-up question: is it preimage-resistant?

> $h(x||y) = \mathrm{AES}_{x}(y)$ so $y = \mathrm{AES}^{-1}_{x}(h(x||y))$. For any hash value $H$ and any 128-bit string $x$, it's trivial to calculate a preimage that begins with $x$.